# R - how to train a model to fit probabilities

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, logistic

I would like to train a model that has a probability (a success rate between 0 and 1) as outcome.

So the data looks like this:

```
feature1  feature2   success_rate
0.1       0.3        0.55
0.3       0.6        0.45
```

I started using *xgboost* (gradient boosting machine) with:

```
"objective" = "reg:logistic"
"eval_metric" = "auc"
```

which means I doing a logistic regression using the Area Under the Curve (AUC) as evaluation function to measure the improvement of the model.

But I understand a logistic regression is usually trained with a categorical target (success or failure), not a probability.
Does this matter? and is this the right approach?

Comment: "Success_rate" cannot be a probability *per se* (because probabilities are unobservable theoretical constructs): most likely it is a ratio of two counts.  Exactly what is it counting?

Comment: @whuber What I call success_rate is the number of success divided by number of observations. For example it could be that for the first line in my example we had 100 observations and 55 success out of them, which is why I noted the success_rate as 0.55.

Comment: Do you know (exactly or approximately) the numbers of successes/failures?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not answered a question in the comments and has not been on the site in a long time.